# Potential leak of an object allocated for Activity indicator window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview, uiapplicationdelegate

I use ActivityIndicatorC class in the application delegate file and alloc object for it but here i get memory leak,

```
self.ActIndicator=[[ActivityIndicatorC alloc] initwithWindow:window];
```

I release ActIndicator this object in the dealloc section but till i am get same potential leak for the above mention code.

Any solution any one can suggest for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if ActIndicator is set to retain property . then there is leak in .h file make 
@property(nonatominc ,retain) to @property(nonatominc ,assign)  or

```
ActivityIndicatorC *theActivity= [[ActivityIndicatorC alloc] initwithWindow:window];
self.ActIndicator=theActivity;
[theActivity release];
```

Answer (score 3):

the object is retained twice. When using `self.ActIndicator =` you invoke the setter, which the compiler created for you by using the `@property(retain,...)` you put in your interface.

```
self.ActIndicator=[[ActivityIndicatorC alloc] initwithWindow:window];
    ^ retainCount + 1                  ^^^^^ and +1 because of this.
```

you could write

```
self.ActIndicator = [[[ActivityIndicatorC alloc] initwithWindow:window] autorelease];
```

or

```
ActIndicator = [[ActivityIndicatorC alloc] initwithWindow:window];
```

And you should change the name to actIndicator or (even better) activityIndicator. Only class names should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually release objects created with alloc-init. So you should write a [ActIndicator release]; or just autorelease it.